# Improving a SQL query when I need to select IN multiple fields combined together

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT date(metrics_session.created_at) as day, COUNT(metrics_session.user_id) as total_logins,  
            sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,metrics_session.created_at,metrics_session.completed_at)) as total_time_spent  
            FROM metrics_session 
            inner join metrics_training on metrics_training.id = metrics_session.training_id 
            inner join metrics_course on metrics_course.id = metrics_training.course_id
            inner join metrics_user_training_cohort on  metrics_training.id = metrics_user_training_cohort.training_id
            inner join auth_user on auth_user.id = metrics_user_training_cohort.user_id

            WHERE metrics_session.created_at >= '2021-01-15'
            AND metrics_session.created_at <= '2022-10-15' 
            AND metrics_session.completed_at IS NOT NULL
            AND metrics_session.user_id In (SELECT user_id from metrics_user_training_cohort  where user_id = 44 and training_id = 4)
            AND metrics_session.training_id In (SELECT training_id from metrics_user_training_cohort  where user_id = 44 and training_id = 4)
                           
            #AND EXISTS(SELECT user_id,training_id from metrics_user_training_cohort  where user_id = 44 and training_id = 4)
            GROUP BY date(metrics_session.created_at) ORDER BY date(metrics_session.created_at)
```

the goal of this query is to select the sessions that were created by some user_id and are linked to some training_id , but only if in the table metrics_user_training_cohort I have that same user_id and training_id in the same row registered.

I managed to achieve that with the 2 last lines before GROUP BY:

```
AND metrics_session.user_id In (SELECT user_id from metrics_user_training_cohort  where user_id = 44 and training_id = 4)
AND metrics_session.training_id In (SELECT training_id from metrics_user_training_cohort  where user_id = 44 and training_id = 4)
```

however the repeated subquery used for the IN statement seems unnecessary to me and likely degrading performance, but I can't quite figure out a better way since the IN statement can only be used with 1 column.

The commented line is not the solution because it just checks for the existence of the row in the table in isolation without association to the sessions, but I left it there to give you a better idea what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: table metrics_user_training_cohort seems to be the boss table so that should be in the from clause then inner joins will ensure everything else follows.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to use `JOIN` or `EXISTS` instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`

These may help:

```
metrics_session:  INDEX(created_at, completed_at, user_id, training_id)
metrics_user_training_cohort:  INDEX(training_id,  user_id)
```